# Is this functional differentiable?

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, bounded-variation

A functional $\Phi$ is differentiable if there exist $F$ and $R$ such that $\Phi(f+h)-\Phi(f)=F(f,h)+R(f,h)$, where $F$ depends linearly on $h$ and $R(f,h) = O(h^2)$.

Define a functional $\Phi(f) = \max_{[0,1]} f$ where $f \in C([0,1])$, then is $\Phi$ differentiable?

Comment: What space are you grabbing $f$ and $h$ from?

Comment: Yeah, a functional is $\Phi : E \to \mathbb R$. We need to know the domain space $E$.

Comment: @Tom Thanks! I update the question.

Comment: What does $o(h^2)$ mean in this context? (It usually means something in terms of *limits*, hence we need a notion of distance on $C(\mathbb R)$, and they are not all equivalent.)

Comment: In consideration of what differentiability means in calculus, I think you want to say $R(f,h) = O(h^2)$ (big-oh) or $R(f,h)=o(h)$ since you intuitively want ``$h^{-1} R(f,h) \to 0$'' as $h \to 0$.

Comment: @Tom Thanks! It is a typo and I correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to pretend $a=0$ and $b=1$ so we will be looking at $C([0,1]\to\mathbb{R})$.

Let's assume that there do exist such an $F$ and $R$. Then $F(0,h+k) = \Phi(h+k)-R(0,h+k)$ and $F(0,h+k) = \Phi(h) + \Phi(k) - R(0,h) - R(0,k)$, but $F(0,h+k) = F(0,h)+F(0,k)$, so you learn that $ R(0,h) + R(0,k) -R(0, h+k)  = \Phi(h)+\Phi(k)-\Phi(h+k)$. Let $C > 0$ and let $h(x) = C(1-2x)$ and $k(x)=C(2x-1)$ so $h+k \equiv 0$. Noting that $0 = R(0,0)$ by assumption and $R(0,0)=R(0,h+k)=0$, you get $R(0,k) + R(0,h) = 2C$; in particular $R(0,k)+R(0,h) \neq o(C)$. However, by assumption, $R(0,k)=o(C)$ and $R(0,h)=o(C)$, which causes a problem since $o(C)+o(C)=o(C)$.

Comment: Let me note that in this solution I am assuming that $C([0,1]\to \mathbb{R})$ is given the $\sup$ norm $\|h\| = \max\{|h(x)| : x \in [0,1]\}$ so that $o(h)$ means $o(\|h\|)$.